# What are the File Permission Signs @ and + for?

Tags: macos, permissions

My mac has folders Shared and Public folders. Their permissions are drwxr-xr-x+ for Public and drwxrwxrwt@ for Shared. What do the signs + and @ mean?

Comment: SO is for programming related questions, maybe try here: http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@ means there are "extended attributes". Type

```
ls -l@
```

to see what they are. With that command, everything with a @ after it will have some extra lines explaining why it has a @. In my experience, the @ usually means a file is going to be opened with an application other than the default (i.e. it might open with a different text editor than you're used to), or occasionally that it's in a different encoding than the default specified by $LANG.

From the manpage for "ls":

> If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information, the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '+' character.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with extended attributes, but the extended security information, aka ACLs, give more fine-grained control over file permissions.  Basically, that + comes up whenever you set permissions on a file/directory beyond the usual choices of read/write/execute for user/group/other.  You can see the ACLs by doing a 'ls -le'.